# The root location is returned in application url

Tags: php, nginx, centos7

I have a Magento application and I try to run it on a CentOS 7 server. I am able to access the application in the browser. However, files like `css` and `js` can't be found because the root location of the application on the server is added to the url.

So for example a file is located at: `https://www.example.com/css/my_file.css`
But the browsers is requesting it from: `https://www.example.com/usr/share/nginx/application_name/css/my_file.css`

How can I get the correct path?

I have Nginx version 1.16.1 installed. Nginx is listening on port 8080 because it is behind Varnish which listens on port 80. This is the vhost:

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name www.example.com;

    root  /usr/share/nginx/application_name;
    index index.php;

    location ^~ /app/ { return 403; }
    location ^~ /db/ { return 403; }
    location ^~ /dev/ { return 403; }
    location ^~ /downloader/pearlib { return 403; }
    location ^~ /downloader/template { return 403; }
    location ^~ /downloader/Maged { return 403; }
    location ~* ^/errors/.+\.xml { return 403; }
    location ^~ /includes/ { return 403; }
    location ^~ /lib/ { return 403; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { return 403; }
    location ^~ /shell/ { return 403; }
    location ^~ /var/ { return 403; }
    location ^~ /varnish/ { return 403; }
    location ^~ /vendor/ { return 403; }
    location ~ .phtml$ { return 403; }

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE base;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 90;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `media` folder of Magento was not writable for nginx and therefore the full path is used to retrieve the files.

Setting the correct permissions made it work.